# Onclick event for hightcharts range selector

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here I have a requirement in highcharts like have range selector like **1d,1w,1m,3m,6m,All** when I click any of the range selector I have to get the response data from server that means ajax call for onclick range selector. I have the below fiddle file has my code . which has the problem like I am adding the data by using

```js
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {

    if(data != null) {
        chart.addSeries({
            name : 'Energy consumption',
            id   : 'energyConsumption',
            data : data
        },{
            name : 'Outdoor Temperature',
            id   : 'outdoorData',
            data : data
        }
        );       
    }

});
```

the above code is working If I changed the data as static or from the JQuery callback response its not working.
my fiddle file is below 
http://jsfiddle.net/UegzK/4/

Please help me on this 
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Two changes:

- `reset_all_buttons` should look that way:

```js
function reset_all_buttons() {
    $.each(chart.rangeSelector.buttons, function(index, value) {
        console.debug("index value is "+index);
        console.debug("value value is : "+ value);
        value.setState(0); 
    });

    series = chart.get('energyConsumption');
    series.remove(); 
    series = chart.get('outdoorData');
    series.remove(); 
}
```

because you don't want to remove 10 times only one series (from your example).

- addSeries can add only one series at the time, and you should set `pointStart` and `pointInterval` as for starting series:

```js
if(data.length > 0) {
    console.log(chart,data);
    chart.addSeries({
        name : 'Energy consumption',
        id   : 'energyConsumption',
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2013, 03, 08,00,00),
        pointInterval: 1 * 3600 * 1000,
        data : [26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6,21.5, 25.2,49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6]
    });

    chart.addSeries({
        name : 'Outdoor Temperature',
        id   : 'outdoorData',
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2013, 03, 08,00,00),
        pointInterval: 1 * 3600 * 1000,
        data : [26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6,21.5, 25.2]
    });       
}
```

And example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/UegzK/5/ (works only for 1w, just to show how should this look like).

Answer (score 0):

instead of your reset_all_buttons function, calling chart.rangeSelector.clickButton(index) will apply highstock's default behavior.  I have a use case where I'm switching between daily and intraday stock prices.  When I switch to a 3day view, I want the more granular intraday prices with equidistant datapoints.  On longer-range views, I want an xAxis with ordinal:true so the points are time-based.  Here's my load event (typescript)

```js
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var chart: HighchartsChartObject = <HighchartsChartObject>this;
            var replaceSeries = (serieses: HighchartsSeriesOptions[]): void => {
                while(chart.series.length > 0) {
                    chart.series[0].remove(false);
                }
                _.each(serieses, (series: HighchartsSeriesOptions) => {
                    chart.addSeries(series, false);
                });
                chart.redraw();
            }
            var buttons = chart.rangeSelector.buttons;
            buttons[0].on("click", function(e) {
                if (chart.rangeSelector.selected !== 0) {
                    _.each(this.xAxis, (xAxis: any): void => {
                        xAxis.options.ordinal = false;
                        xAxis.options.minRange = undefined;
                    });
                    replaceSeries(chartDataService.buildDataSeries(true));
                }
                chart.rangeSelector.clickButton(0);
            });
            _.each(buttons, (button, index: number): void => {
                if (index !== 0) {
                    button.on("click", function(e) {
                        if (chart.rangeSelector.selected === 0) {
                            _.each(this.xAxis, (xAxis: any): void => {
                                xAxis.options.ordinal = true;
                                xAxis.options.minRange = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7; // 1wk for daily data
                            });
                            replaceSeries(chartDataService.buildDataSeries(false));
                        }
                        chart.rangeSelector.clickButton(index);
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```